# I am not able to install any modules in python on windows

Tags: python, syntax, module

```
>>> pip install pillow
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install pillow
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pip install selenium
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install selenium
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: You're typing these commands in a python interactive shell, but instead they belong on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
python -m pip install pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't install is because you are on a python notebook type thing. Go to the terminal or command prompt then use the command.